# How to register manually-created decorator instance

Tags: c#, decorator, simple-injector

Typically, to register some configuration value using constructor injection I would do this:

```
string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeSetting"];
container.Register<IService>(new Service(setting));
```

How do you accomplish something similar, in order to pass a configuration value into a decorator constructor?

Is the only means to create some configuration provider class which could get injected into the decorator?   Seems like RegisterDecorator should have an overload which allows manually newing the class as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. If that part of the object graph is simple, building the object graph by hand might give the best results:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<IService>(new ServiceDecorator(
    setting,
    new RealService()));

// or 
container.Register<IService>(() => new ServiceDecorator(
    setting,
    new RealService()));
```

There is no delegate overload for `RegisterDecorator` in Simple Injector, which means that you can't register a decorator using `RegisterDecorator` that is hand-wired, but there some alternative approaches.

You can extract the setting value into its own class. This allows the that abstraction to get injected into the decorator:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<MySetting>(new MySetting(setting));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IService), typeof(ServiceDecorator));

public ServiceDecorator : IService {
    public ServiceDecorator(MySetting setting, IService decoratee) { }
}
```

Or you can inject the setting into a property of the decorator:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IService), typeof(ServiceDecorator));
container.RegisterInitializer<ServiceDecorator>(dec => dec.Setting = setting);

public ServiceDecorator : IService {
    public string Setting { get; set; }
    public ServiceDecorator(IService decoratee) { }
}
```

Or you can make the `Setting` a static property:

```cs
ServiceDecorator.Setting = setting;
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IService), typeof(ServiceDecorator));
```

If the decorator itself can't be changed, you can derive from that class:

```cs
public ServiceDecoratorWithSetting : ServiceDecorator {
    public static string Setting { get; set; }
    public ServiceDecorator(IService decoratee) : base(Setting, decoratee) { }
}

ServiceDecoratorWithSetting.Setting = setting;
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IService), typeof(ServiceDecoratorWithSetting));
```

A last option is to [override parameter injection behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-parameter-injection-behavior), but that's a bit more complex, and I usually only advice this in integration scenarios.